# Ktor application not running on my computer

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I am trying to learn to use ktor and I'm trying to display the text "Hello Ktor" at the root path but all I keep getting is this site can't be reached.
This is my code:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

private val userData = "{\"users\": [\"Timi\", \"Tomi\", \"Temi\"]}"

@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello Ktor", ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you testing your code? Are you visiting `http://localhost`? You should try `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. I was visiting http://0.0.0.0:8080/ instead of http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine.
I think you just need to access it correctly from browser.
Try

> 127.0.0.1:8080

or

> localhost:8080

or simply follow nice tutorial from [official website.](https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html)

[image]

Comment: I still get `This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I created the sample project with https://start.ktor.io/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run without a main?

Did you follow this guide? https://ktor.io/quickstart/quickstart/gradle.html#intellij-extract-out-configuration-data

If you want to start from main, use `embeddedServer`. Otherwise you have to set the `mainClassName`.